# OpenSubtitles api android class

Tags: android, api, rest, android-studio, subtitle

I'm having trouble getting data from OpenSubtitles api. I have looked at many examples for java and python. Below is the class I'm trying to use to authenticate with OpenSubtitles api. After that I want to make request that will return a list of items I can pass to my recyclerview.

```
package com.shivito.subreader;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class OpensubsRequest {
    static String username;
    static String password;
    static String language;
    static String useragent;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public static void makerequest(){

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Log.d("here","nope");
                    URL Opensubs = new URL("https://api.opensubtitles.org/xml-rpc");
                    URL url = new URL("https", "api.opensubtitles.org", 443, "/xml-rpc");
                    URLConnection uc = Opensubs.openConnection();
                    Log.d("working",uc.toString());
                    uc.addRequestProperty("username",username);
                    uc.addRequestProperty("password",password);
                    uc.addRequestProperty("language",language);
                    uc.addRequestProperty("useragent",useragent);
                    uc.connect();
                    Log.d("anythingnow", String.valueOf(uc.getAllowUserInteraction()));

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Okay so in the above class I am trying to send my login information to the api then I try to check if it was successful by reading the response from(uc.getAllowUserInteraction()). Up to this point it always says false. Of course I'm likely not doing this right and I hope someone can point me in the right direction. Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry to bump this but its been a few days. Does anyone have some suggestion for me to communicate with OpenSubtitles api?

Comment: I have made some progress using this git https://github.com/gturri/aXMLRPC

Comment: however now when trying to searchsubtitles I get error "status=408 Invalid parameters"

Comment: here is the line of code for the search request: Object test = client.call("SearchSubtitles",Token,"en", "", "", "", "blade", "", "", "");